# MySQL does not start on xampp , start after five seconds and it's gone

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-04  1:23:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 1374414; transaction id 1525
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [ERROR] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable 'inoodb_force_recovery=1'
2020-07-04  1:23:54 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: You have **inoodb**_force_recovery=1 variable being set in my.cnf/my.ini setting which the spelling is incorrect. It should be **innodb**_force_recovery=1. If the variable is not required, just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must edit the my.con/ini

And put

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

**after** the tag `[mysqld]`

The other you have to delete

And **after recovering** **disable it again**